# How to store the last n characters of a string to concatenate to the user input in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace, concatenation, slice

In Head First Learn to Code there is a short exercise that involves creating a function to replace placeholders in a text. If the end of a placeholder is **!!!!!** this code only returns the last exclamation mark. How could we modify the code so that when the user provides the word **SPAM** as input in place of **NOUN!!!,**, the processed_line would return **SPAM!!!,**?

This is the code:

```
placeholders = ['NOUN', 'VERB_ING', 'ADJECTIVE', 'VERB']
endings = ['.', ',', ';', ':', '?', '!']


def process_line(line):
    global placeholders
    global endings
    processed_line = ''

    words = line.split()


    for word in words:
        stripped = word.strip(',.;:?!')
        if stripped in placeholders:
            answer = input(f'Enter a {stripped}:')
            processed_line = processed_line + answer
            if word[-1] in endings:
                processed_line = processed_line + word[-1] + ' '
            else:
                processed_line = processed_line + ' '
        else:
            processed_line = processed_line + word + ' '
    return processed_line + '\n'
```

Comment: Can you explain what you’re trying to do a bit more? You also haven’t mentioned what the problem actually is.

Comment: The problem is that it should only change the placeholder, not the punctuation marks. With if ```word[-1] in endings:```I can retrieve the last punctuation mark. But I would like to return with the input an undetermined amount of punctuation marks. For example, if we find something like **VERB!!!!** or **NOUN!!?*, it returns EATING!!!! and SPAM!!? and not just EATING! and SPAM?

Answer (score 0):

You stripped the punctuation characters out to begin with. Just add them back in later and it should work:

```
placeholders = ['NOUN', 'VERB_ING', 'ADJECTIVE', 'VERB']
endings = ['.', ',', ';', ':', '?', '!']


def process_line(line):
    global placeholders
    global endings
    processed_line = ''

    words = line.split()

    def keep(string, chars):
      return ''.join([i for i in string if i in chars])

    for word in words:
        stripped = word.strip(',.;:?!')
        leftovers = keep(word, ',.;:?!')
        if stripped in placeholders:
            loc = placeholders.index(stripped)
            answer = input(f'Enter a {stripped}:')
            processed_line += answer + leftovers # here is what's new
            if word[-1] in endings:
                processed_line = processed_line + word[-1] + ' '
            else:
                processed_line = processed_line + ' '
        else:
            processed_line = processed_line + word + ' '
    return processed_line + '\n'

print(process_line('hello, NOUN! I am Joe.'))
```